# Find all records from database where date is from - to

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

How can I return all entities in a list for specific date range or for current month if I've only a parameter

```
@CreatedDate
@Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Instant createdAt;
```

The result I would like to get is a List of this entity where the createdAt is between `from` `to` or return it for the current month. Is there a possibility to perform those actions using just the repository without `@Query` or not, any ideas?

Comment: did you try List<MyEntity> findByCreatedAtBetween(Instant startDate, Instant endDate); ?

Comment: @AdinaFometescu No, I haven't also the question is do I have to pass an Instant as a parameter if the createdAt is `Instant` type or may I pass `Date`?

Comment: What you pass as parameters must have the same type as createdAt. What hibernate will actually do is something like this: select * from my_table where created_at between 2019-10-24 and 2019-10-23.

Comment: I see thank you! I will try this out, and leave a comment if it works for me or not.

Comment: @AdinaFometescu I've a problem how to test it, not sure how to pass an Instant from, Instant to in GET request. I wanted pass it as parameters from="2019-10-15" and so on. Do I need to pass it as String and then inside the controller convert the date to an instant?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query-by-date Here is a nice example on how to use with dates as string. If you want to use Instant you can use date.toInstant().

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `@Query` annotation and the [SpEL support](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions) to calculate upper and lower bound for your date range.